# Strict digit check after a particular character using REGEX in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, regex

In my db data are stored like below:

```
Q_101_B1
Q_101_B2
Q_101_B17
Q_101_Bch1
Q_101_Ben1
Q_101_B238
Q_101_B
```

I have to pull only those data which has digits strictly after char '`B`', thus in this case it should pull all the data except these two `Q_101_Bch1`, `Q_101_Ben1`.

**I have tried with this query:**

```
select lang from test_table where lang REGEXP  '^[Q_101_B]|[0-9]'
```

But unfortunately its pulling all of them.

**What should be the exact regex for this query?**

Note: `Q_101_B` can be a different string which will come dynamically, and I will append this while building the query inside my PHP code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original pattern would match any string beginning with the characters `Q`, `_`, `1`, `0`, or `B` or containing a decimal digit.

Try using this pattern instead:

```
select lang from test_table where lang REGEXP  '^Q_101_B[0-9]'
```

This will match any string beginning with `Q_101_B` followed by a decimal digit.

However, since you indicated you want `Q_101_B` to be returned as well (with no decimal), you might use this:

```
select lang from test_table where lang REGEXP  '^Q_101_B([0-9]|$)'
```

This will match any string beginning with `Q_101_B` followed by either a decimal digit or the end of the string.

You can see a demonstration of this pattern [here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5EQ_101_B%28%5B0-9%5D%7C$%29&input=Q_101_B1%0AQ_101_B2%0AQ_101_B17%0AQ_101_Bch1%0AQ_101_Ben1%0AQ_101_B238%0AQ_101_B).

Also, since you stated you that `Q_101_B` is just a sample string, and may be replaced by a different string at run-time, I'd recommend you look at using the [`preg_quote`](https://www.php.net/preg_quote) method to safely escape the literal within your pattern.

Comment: @KshirodraMeher You accepted my answer; does that mean this solution is working for you after all?